# Существуют ли плагины в jquery которые расчитывают время восхода и захода солнца?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Существуют ли команды в jquery которые расчитывают время восхода и захода солнца?

Comment: В jQuery таких команд нет, только в плагинах

Comment: А не проще ли эту информацию парсить? Какую задачу вы решаете?

Comment: @АлександрСемикашев зачем парсить, если можно на клиенте посчитать?

Answer (score 1):

Есть https://github.com/mourner/suncalc

SunCalc - это небольшая BSD-лицензионная библиотека JavaScript для определения положения солнца, фаз солнечного света (времена восхода, заката, сумерки и т. Д.), Положение луны и фаза Луны для данного места и времени, созданная Владимиром Агафонкиным (@mourner) as Часть проекта SunCalc.net.

```
// get today's sunlight times for London
var times = SunCalc.getTimes(new Date(), 51.5, -0.1);

// format sunrise time from the Date object
var sunriseStr = times.sunrise.getHours() + ':' + times.sunrise.getMinutes();

// get position of the sun (azimuth and altitude) at today's sunrise
var sunrisePos = SunCalc.getPosition(times.sunrise, 51.5, -0.1);

// get sunrise azimuth in degrees
var sunriseAzimuth = sunrisePos.azimuth * 180 / Math.PI;
```

Comment: Существуют ли команды jquery, которые определяют смысл жизни?

Comment: @BeastWinterwolf зачем jquery если ответ уже давно найден и он — 42?

Comment: @BeastWinterwolf `alert(42);`

Comment: @АлексейШиманский а вопрос какой?